# how to split a file with nbytes and using head and tail

Tags: linux, bash, tail, head, wc

i'm trying to make a script that split a file divided by nbytes.
I already note this but i want to use head and tail and not using split as me.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ];then
    exit 1
fi
if [ $# -eq 1 ];then
    exit 1
fi
if [ $2 -eq 0 ];then
    exit 1
fi
if [ ! -f "$1" ];then
    exit 1
fi

split -d -b 1024 bigfile.bin bigfile.bin.
```

It giving this :

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 madushan madushan 1024 déc.  10 17:34 bigfile.bin.00
-rw-rw-r-- 1 madushan madushan 1024 déc.  10 17:34 bigfile.bin.01
-rw-rw-r-- 1 madushan madushan 1024 déc.  10 17:34 bigfile.bin.02
-rw-rw-r-- 1 madushan madushan 1024 déc.  10 17:34 bigfile.bin.03
-rw-rw-r-- 1 madushan madushan 1024 déc.  10 17:34 bigfile.bin.04
-rw-rw-r-- 1 madushan madushan 1024 déc.  10 17:34 bigfile.bin.05
-rw-rw-r-- 1 madushan madushan 1024 déc.  10 17:34 bigfile.bin.06
-rw-rw-r-- 1 madushan madushan 1024 déc.  10 17:34 bigfile.bin.07
-rw-rw-r-- 1 madushan madushan 1024 déc.  10 17:34 bigfile.bin.08
-rw-rw-r-- 1 madushan madushan  784 déc.  10 17:34 bigfile.bin.09
```

Comment: `split -d -b "$2" "$1" "$1"`?

Comment: yes 2 parameters, one for bytes and other one for filename. The last one is for rename the differents files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a light-weight version of split with `bash` (+head, +tail). However, it will not be very efficient, as you will need to read the file  times, where N=totalsize/nbytes. For small files, the overhead is small, for large file, very expensive.

```
nbytes=1024
file=bigfile.bin
k=0
i=0
while tail --bytes=+$((nbytes*i)) < $file | head --bytes=$nbytes > $file.work ; do
    # Stop unless segment has data
    [ -s "$file.work" ] || break
    let i++
    echo "Segment: $i"

    mv "$file.work" "$file.$i"
done
rm -f $file.work
```

If OK with just using head, possible to make is more efficient for large files. It will read the input only once, with no need to re-read anything.

```
nbytes=1024
file=bigfile.bin
k=0
i=0
(
    while head --bytes=$nbytes > $file.work ; do
        [ -s "$file.work" ] || break
        let ++i
        mv "$file.work" "$file.$i"
    done
) < $file
rm -f $file.work
```

Also consider using 'dd', which has more powerful logic for large files.

Comment: THanks for your implement of split, that i was searching for. I'm trying to understand your code but i know it's not as efficient that split

Comment: @YoloSama what shell do you use ? bash has printf, what is the error message ? I've modified the script to avoid printf.